# How to suspend thread using thread's id?

Tags: java, multithreading

Code which I am trying

```
public void killJob(String thread_id)throws RemoteException{   
Thread t1 = new Thread(a);   
    t1.suspend();   
}
```

How can we suspend/pause thread based on its id?
Thread.suspend is deprecated,There must be some alternative to achieve this.
I have thread id I want to suspend and kill the thread.

Edit:  I used this.

```
AcQueryExecutor a=new AcQueryExecutor(thread_id_id);
Thread t1 = new Thread(a); 
t1.interrupt(); 
while (t1.isInterrupted()) { 
    try { 
       Thread.sleep(1000); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
       t1.interrupt(); 
       return; 
    } 
}
```

But I am not able to stop this thread.

Comment: Oh I see, you added a question.  You don't put the `isInterrupted()` check in the main thread.  You put it inside of the `AcQueryExecutor` code.  The `AcQueryExecutor` thread should be checking to see if its own thread (itself) has been interrupted.  The `while` loop in the caller should never run because `t1.interrupted()` will always be true after you just called `t1.interrupt()`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make this more plain.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can we suspend/pause thread based on its id?  ... I have thread id I want to suspend and kill the thread.

The right way to kill a thread these days is to `interrupt()` it.  That sets the `Thread.isInterrupted()` to true and causes `wait()`, `sleep()`, and a couple other methods to throw `InterruptedException`.

Inside of your thread code, you should be doing something like the following which checks to make sure that it has not been interrupted.

```
 // run our thread while we have not been interrupted
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     // do your thread processing code ...
 }
```

Here's an example of how to handle interrupted exception inside of a thread:

```
 try {
     Thread.sleep(...);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // always good practice because throwing the exception clears the flag
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     // most likely we should stop the thread if we are interrupted
     return;
 }
```

The right way to *suspend* a thread is a bit harder.  You could set some sort of `volatile boolean suspended` flag for the thread that it would pay attention to.  You could also use `object.wait()` to suspend a thread and then `object.notify()` to start it running again.

Comment: execution nerver enters in the above block. I have added this AcQueryExecutor a=new AcQueryExecutor(thread_id_id);
 Thread t1 = new Thread(a);
t1.interrupt();
  while (t1.isInterrupted()) {
   try {                 
    Thread.sleep(1000);     
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {          
     t1.interrupt();          
     return;      
     }  
    }

Comment: I don't quite understand @happy.  Have you started the thread?  That code will work if the thread has been started and has been interrupted.

Comment: @happy not(!) operator is missing in the while loop and corrected now.

Comment: Thanks! Gray, it is an great answer!

Comment: Thanks a ton. Was looking for this kind of functionality.  One question, is there any memory leak since that thread is actually not killed. Anything else that i could do to cleanly kill that thread ??

Comment: If the thread returns and exits then it can be reaped.  If it is still running then it won't be @Raghav.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a [PauseableThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669623/823393) implementation recently that uses a `ReadWriteLock` internally. Use one of these or a variant and you should be able to pause your threads.

As to pausing them by id, a little googling suggests [a way to iterate over all threads](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ListThreads.html) which looks like it should work. `Thread` has exposed a [getId](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId%28%29) method for some time.

Killing the thread is different. [@Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11020048/823393) has neatly covered that one.