# Is AtomicBoolean needed to create a cancellable thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, volatile

I often use the following pattern to create a cancellable thread:

```
public class CounterLoop implements Runnable {

    private volatile AtomicBoolean cancelPending = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!cancelPending.get()) {
            //count
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        cancelPending.set(true);
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure that cancelPending MUST be a AtomicBoolean. Can we just use a normal boolean in this case?

Comment: rule of the thumb: if you do not use CAS, you do not need AtomicXXX. 2nd rule: if you need test/modify (and modify can go into multiple states) you need CAS. Hence, in your case you don't need AtomicXXX but you can just use Thread.interrupt instead. `interrupt()` is more reaching as well (can cancel blocking and might be able to cancel IO). In your case if you go w/ AtomicXXX, you should make it final, not volatile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using both `volatile` and `AtomicBoolean` is unnecessary.  If you declare the `cancelPending` variable as `final` as follows:

```
private final AtomicBoolean cancelPending = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

the JLS semantics for `final` fields mean that synchronization (or `volatile`) will not be needed.  All threads will see the correct value for the `cancelPending` reference. [JLS 17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) states:

> *"An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields."*

... but there are no such guarantees for normal fields; i.e. not `final` and not `volatile`.

You could also just declare `cancelPending` as a `volatile boolean` ... since you don't appear to be using the test-and-set capability of `AtomicBoolean`.

However, if you used a non-volatile `boolean` you would need to use `synchronized` to ensure that all threads see an up-to-date copy of the `cancelPending` flag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `volatile boolean` instead with no issues.

Note that this only applies in cases much like this where the boolean is only being changed to a specific value (`true` in this case). If the boolean might be changed to either `true` or `false` at any time then you may need an `AtomicBoolean` to detect and act on race conditions.

However - the pattern you describe has an innate smell. By looping on a boolean (`volatile` or not) you are likely to find yourself trying to insert some sort of `sleep` mechanism or having to interrupt your thread.

A much cleaner route is to split up the process into finer steps. I recently posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669623/823393) covering the options of pausing threads that may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. Because if you will change the boolean value from another thread without proper synchronization then this change can be invisible to another threads. You can use `valotile boolean` in your case to make any modification visible to all threads.

Comment: actually, you need either `volatile` or `final` ... due to the way that the memory model works.

Comment: I think that Hiep does not want to change the value of `cancelPending ` so the `final` keyword is not needed, but will be more accurate.

Comment: It is actually, really needed ... even if nothing modifies the variable.  Read my Answer, and the JLS section I've linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can either use a non volatile AtomicBoolean (relying on its built in thread safety), or use any other volatile variable.

According to the Java Memory Model ([JMM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)), both options result in a properly synchronized program, where the read and write of the cancelPending variable can't produce a data race.

Comment: Actually you need either `volatile` or `final`; see the JLS link in my Answer.

Comment: @StephenC: You are right - in the general case the "final" is required when the variable isn't declared as volatile. However, in practice, usually the thread that interrupts is the same thread where the flag is initialized. In this specific scenario the "happens-before" relation is guaranteed between the writes and reads.

Answer (score 0):

Using a volatile boolean variable in this context is safe, though some may consider it bad practice. Consult [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805192/is-a-volatile-int-in-java-thread-safe) to see why.

Your solution of using an Atomic* variable seems the best option, even though the synchronization may introduce unnecessary overhead in comparison to a volatile variable.

You can also use a critical section

```
Object lock = new Object();

@Override
public void run() {
  synchronized (lock) {
    if (cancelPending) {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

or a synchronized method.

```
synchronized public boolean shouldStop() {
  return shouldStop;
}

synchronized public void setStop(boolean stop) {
  shouldStop = stop;
}
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I disagree. It will work. Synchronized section ensures memory refresh.

Comment: I stand corrected - I apologise for for my hastiness and withdraw most of my comment (and the downvote). However, I still believe using `synchronized` to flush cache is overkill when `volatile` is available.

Comment: @StephenC My answer's first sentence means "using a normal boolean is a solution that may work sometimes, but sometimes may not" which in turn should be interpreted as "do not use it". I will edit it though, since this SE is not a place for such remarks.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon thanks. Using volatile has it's pitfalls, as I stated in my edit. I would not suggest using it, even though in this case it is safe. Doing `var = !var` would not be safe any more.