# Do different threads see the same version of a object referenced by a local variable?

Tags: java, multithreading

Are multiple threads guaranteed to see the same version of a shared object to which they have a reference?  Here is a code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    new Thread(){
      public void run() { possibly read and mutate flag }
    }.start();

    new Thread(){
      public void run() { possibly read and mutate flag }
    }.start();

    while (!flag.get()) {
      Thread.yield();
    }
}
```

To be clear, I am wondering whether writes by the child threads to the shared object are seen by the parent and sibling threads.

Comment: What do you mean, the same version? The value could be different (concurrency), but yes, they share the same variable.

Comment: I would like to know if changes to flag made in one thread are seen immediately by the other two threads.

Comment: @user2864740 Using the words "crap" and "bogus" is not constructive; the proper mechanisms are downvoting or voting to close.  I asked the question as I understood it. I have told my students that StackOverflow is a safe place to ask questions because insulting language like yours is rare.

Comment: Stephen C has provided a better explanation saying that two threads are actually seeing same boolean value contained inside the object flag.  I think the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are multiple threads guaranteed to see the same version of a shared local variable in their scope.

In general, it depends on what you mean by "the same version".  It also depends on the *nature* of the variable (e.g. how it is declared and initialized) ... and on how the threads use it.

(In general, Java doesn't do "versions" of variables.  A thread accessing a shared variable or object will either see the latest state, or it won't.  If it sees a state that isn't the latest state, then there are no guarantees as to what it will see.  In particular, it may see something that doesn't directly correspond to *any* notional version of the object ... due to word-tearing and other cache-related memory artefacts.)

---

In your example you are using a `final` local variable within an inner class (in this case you have two anonymous inner classes).  When you do that, the compiler creates a corresponding *synthetic* variable in the inner class that is initialized with the value of the variable in the method scope.  The compiled inner class then refers to the value of the synthetic variable instead of the original variable.

In your example, it is guaranteed that the inner classes (e.g. your threads) will see the same (reference) value as in the original variable.  Furthermore, it is guaranteed that they will (at least initially) see a consistent snapshot of whatever object it is that it references.  (And since it is an `AtomicXxxx` class, it will always be consistent for all threads that can access it.  Guaranteed.)

---

OK, so what about other cases:

- If `flag` was a static or instance field that was also `final`, then we wouldn't have synthetic variables, and each nested class would be referencing the same shared  variable.  But it would all still work.
- If `flag` was a static or instance field and it wasn't `final`, but nothing changed the field (after creating of the threads) then it would still be OK.  (Though you could argue that this is *fragile* ... because something *could* change the field.)
- If `flag` was a static or instance field and it wasn't `final` or `volatile`, then the threads would initially see the same state as the parent thread.  But if either the original thread or any of the other threads changed the variable (etcetera), then the others are *not* guaranteed to see the new state ... unless they respective threads synchronize properly.

---

> I would like to know if changes to flag made in one thread are seen immediately by the other two threads.

As I said above, it depends ...

- In your example, the answer is "yes", because you use a `final` reference to `AtomicBoolean`.
- If you had declared `flag` as a `boolean` and marked it as `volatile`, then the answer would be "yes".
- If you had declared `flag` as a `boolean` and non-volatile, then the answer would be "no".
- If `flag` was a `final` reference to an ordinary object with a mutable non-volatile `boolean` field, then the answer would also be "no".  (The threads would all see the same object, but they wouldn't consistently see the latest state.  The solution would be to use synchronized getters and setters, or equivalent.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two threads share the same final AtomicBoolean which is a class used to set the truth value.  The variable flag itself can't be recreated because it is final.  But you can perform actions on it to set value.  Just like a final int[] can't be assigned to different size but you can change the value of what's inside.

```
final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
new Thread(){
     public void run(){
         try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         flag.set(true);    
     }
 }.start();
 new Thread(){
     public void run(){
         flag.set(false);   
     }
 }.start();
 Thread.sleep(200);// comment this line, you see different results
 System.out.println(flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

The *local variable* is *not* shared<sup>1</sup>, and being `final` means that there would be no worry of it changing even if it was the case. (A question about *member variables* would result in a different response although, excluding constructor leakage, a `final` member would provide the same guarantees.)

The *same object* is shared across threads; it will be the same object and will adhere to the defined [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) contract.

> A boolean value that may be updated atomically. See the java.util.concurrent.atomic package specification for description of the properties of atomic variables.

In short the [package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) specifies the following which in turn guarantees happens-before relationships.

> - get has the memory effects of reading a volatile variable.
> - set has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a volatile variable.

There are many questions relating to the thread-safey of volatile (and AtomicXYZ objects), eg. see [Is a volatile int in Java thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805192/is-a-volatile-int-in-java-thread-safe) and [Is AtomicBoolean needed to create a cancellable thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875189/is-atomicboolean-needed-to-create-a-cancellable-thread?lq=1)

---

<sup>1</sup> Anonymous types, including Java 8 lambdas, do *not* create closures/lexical bindings to variables in scope and as such are *not* capable of sharing local variables; rather variables are synthesized with the *value* of the final (or effectively final) variable from the enclosing scope which is bound when the anonymous type is instantiated.

Comment: Thank you, although the shared object being an AtomicBoolean isn't really relevant to my question.  I chose it because it is a mutable object.  The question is really whether changes to shared objects are seen immediately by other threads.

Comment: You are of course correct that the local variable is not shared.  I've removed that from my question.

Comment: @user2864740: First a final variable created by new will have its value changed if true/false is the value.  The only thing is final is its address or say reference.  It will not be allowed to be created but in this case, the flag can change to be true or false by the threads.  Second, a final variable can be shared by the threads in his case.

Comment: @Splash A *final (or effectively final)* **variable** is *never shared* by anonymous types - this includes Java 8 Lambdas. This is because Java does *not* keep "closure/lexical bindings" but rather introduces *distinct* synthesized variables. Once again, then we are off to the **object** being shared and the contract for an AtomicBoolean have been outlined and linked above. (Put another way: the *variable* is not a boolean and thus cannot be true or false and as such the *variable* is never re-assigned, even if non-final. Rather the *object* is modified/mutated per the AtomicBoolean API.)

Comment: @user2864740, I see what you are saying now.  I didn't have that knowledge as said in your note.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, yes.  The Java Language Specification says that calling Thread.start() [*synchronizes-with* all previous actions on the calling thread:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)

> An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts.

This creates a [*happens-before* relationship between all writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) on your main thread (including any writes the constructor of the AtomicBoolean made to initialize itself) are made visible to the thread your main thread started.

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

So basically you are good to go.  Your AtomicBoolean object is visible to both threads, and they both see the same object.

This pattern is called [Safe Publication,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication) btw.  You use it to safely publish an object you create (like your AtomicBoolean) so that other threads can see it.  (And yes, `Thread.start()` isn't on the list there of ways to safely publish an object because `Thread.start()` isn't general enough.  But it's the same idea, and works the same way.)

Comment: Thank you, although your answer doesn't address whether each thread's updates are seen by the others.

Comment: Well, it's the same object, so it would have to, right?  Or did I miss some other part of the question?

Comment: OK, based on your edit, when you see something in the documentation that says "guarantee happens-before relationship" that means yes, the writes (updates) are seen immediately.  In this case, both the Safe Publication and package documentation (pointed out in the other answer you commented on) are needed to establish that everything here is working.  But it's all there, so it works.