# How to pause thread in java?

Tags: java

So what's the best way to pause a thread? So far I have something like this: In main loop of the thread, first line is:

```
while (paused == true) {
   Thread.sleep(refreshRate);
}
```

And it works perfercly. I can change paused state pressing P key. But Im looking for better, more professional solution. I know about reentrant locks and conditions. So I could use them on the thread. And then presing P would release singalAll() method. But it would slow my app a lot because of synchronization which I don't really need in this thread. So what is the best, most perform way to solve it? Maybe using synchronization blocks?

```
synchronized (new Object()) {

}
```

Then just part of code would be synchronized. Or maybe I should use semaphores?

Comment: Whats wrong with Thread.sleep()? do you want tonsleep, or do you want to wait until an action occurs where then to continue?

Comment: Wait until action occurs where then to continue is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a wait/notify scheme such as:

1. Create an atomic boolean flag in the thread to be paused.
2. When the flag is set the thread should call wait() on a lock object
3. When you want to unpause the thread reset the flag and call notify() on the lock object

Answer (score 0):

Use wait() and notify()

```
Object waitLock = new Object();

//...


// waiter Thread
synchronized (waitLock) {
   waitLock.wait();
}


// wake up with

waitLock.notify();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [PauseableThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669623/823393) like the one I posted a while ago in answer to a question much like yours.

It uses `ReadWriteLock`s to implement so you don't have the overhead of synchronization.