# Using sleep in thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, multi-user

I am planning to implementing a multiuser system.

Can I use sleep inside threads. Just want to know will it cause any issues while running multiple threads.

Comment: You can, but it's probably not a good idea. Try to use an event-based approach.

Comment: I am new to java. What is event-based approach.

Comment: What research have you done?  What have you tried?  You have to show work if you want someone to take the time to answer your question.

Comment: I will try to understand event-based approach myself.

Answer (score 1):

> I am planning to implementing a multiuser system.

Good

> Can I use sleep inside threads.

Yes

> Just want to know it will cause any blocking issues while running multiple threads.

No

However - it is advisable to avoid sleeping in threads unless you really have no choice. You should use inter-thread communications techniques such as `BlockingQueue`s instead if you can.

Some kind of [PauseableThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669623/823393) may be a better option.