# Threads stopping, suspending, and resuming

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm writing a code that involves JFrame, and a thread.
The thread should take the text from a text field and write it into text area.
I have 4 buttons as follows:

1. "Start" to start the thread.
2. "Stop" which stops the thread.
3. "Pause" which pause and continues the thread.
4. and "Exit" which stops the thread and exits the program.

I've created the thread and implemented "run()" function in frame's constructor, here it is:

```
WritingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String s = WrittenText.getText();
        while(true)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
                {
                    WritingArea.append("" + s.charAt(j));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((int)ThreadSpeedSpinner.getValue());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                }
                WritingArea.append("\n");
            }   
            WritingArea.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

and these are the buttons:

```
JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(!WritingThread.isAlive())
            WritingThread.start();
    }
});
JButton btnStop = new JButton("Stop");
btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(WritingThread.isAlive())
            WritingThread.stop();
    }
});
btnPause = new JButton("Pause");
btnPause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(!isPaused)
        {
            if(WritingThread.isAlive())
            {
                WritingThread.suspend();
                btnPause.setText("Continue");
                isPaused = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WritingThread.resume();
            btnPause.setText("Pause");
        }
    }
});
JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        WritingThread.stop();
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

I have two problems showing up:

1. When I use `stop()`, `suspend()`, or `resume()`, I get a warning says "The method from the type Thread is deprecated".
2. When I run the program, I start the thread, then stop it, then try to start it I have this exception

   ```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
       at com.HomeWork.HomeWork5$6.actionPerformed(HomeWork5.java:140)
       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
   ```

I don't want direct answers, I want to understand why I'm getting these errors, and if there any resources I should go through.
P.S. I searched for an answer a lot and didn't get anything explaining this problem.
Thanks

Comment: avoid using `stop()` ans `suspend()` on threads http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: You can't restart thread once it's stopped. `suspend()` is deprecated. Read basic Oracle online manual about threads: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Read the API documentation on these methods. It explains why these methods are deprecated and it also explains that you cannot restart a thread.

Comment: A thread isn't like a video that you can just start/stop at will.

Comment: I [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10669623/823393) on this some time ago.

Comment: @VictorSorokin Thanks, I didn't know that.
Reading the decumantation right now :)

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Thanks for editing it. btw how did you do it :D

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon it doesn't cover the whole issue, plus, it didn't mention the exception :\

Comment: You are better off avoiding threads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread#Swing_and_thread_safety - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html sounds better.

Comment: @zapl I have to study it first, and study why should I avoid it, then do so, thanks for the idea. :)

Comment: @MaHeRHeJaZi - *It doesn't cover ...* which is why I posted as a comment not an answer.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon ah, ok, sorry and thanks for your interest :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads acquire lock on objects. And the most important part of multithreading
is to safely interweave the threads, so that all the threads can use the resource (object).
If not dealt with correctly, it leads to **deadlock**.

When you use `stop()`, you are killing the thread. That thread is gone forever. It
may lead the objects, that stopped thread had acquired, in a **inconsistent state**.

`suspend()` is deprecated, because once the thread is suspended other threads won't get the
resource, since the suspended thread holds a lock on it.

The image below describes how threads should be correctly used.
Use `sleep()`, `wait()`, and `notify()` for interleaving the threads efficiently.

[image]

Comment: May i know the reference of the image ?